# Use AJAX/JQuery to submit form and show results without reload

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

Im trying to use jquery and ajax to submit a form and show the results without reloading. Like your typical ajax commenting setup.

My HTML is setup like this:

```
    <form id="create_new_heading" action="/display.php?brand=1" method="post">

          <label for="entry">Heading:</label><br/>
          <input type="text" id="heading" name="heading" maxlength="150"/><br/>

          <input type="submit" value="Add this Heading" />
    </form>
    <div id="result">

   </div>
```

JS:

```
    <script>
      /* attach a submit handler to the form */
      $("#create_new_heading").submit(function(event) {

        /* stop form from submitting normally */
        event.preventDefault(); 

        /* get some values from elements on the page: */
        var $form = $( this ),
            term = $form.find( 'input[name="heading"]' ).val(),
            url = $form.attr( 'action' );

        /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
        $.post( url, { s: term },
          function( data ) {
              var content = $( data ).find( '#test_me' );
              $( "#result" ).empty().append( content );
          }
        );
      });
    </script>
```

Form Processor looks like this:

```
public function write($p) {
    if ( $_POST['type'] )
      $type = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type']);
    if ( $_POST['heading'])
      $heading = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['heading']);
    if ( $type && $heading ) {
      $uniqueid = uniqid();
      $sql = "INSERT INTO headings VALUES('$type','$heading','$uniqueid')";
      return mysql_query($sql);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

I attempted to follow the jquery documentation for implementing this but I can't seem to get it to work. The form submits, and the entry gets put into the database but I still have to refresh the page to see the new entry. Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check on firebug, whether caching is screwing the request.
I had a similar problem and started giving a random_id along with the param and
it worked fine.

Proper way could be enable Cache-Control header (or) setting a past time as expiry time.

Comment: How would I check this in firebug?

Comment: If you dont know firebug, you can check it by watching sever logs.

Learn to use firebug if u are working with html, css, jquery.

1. Install firebug from https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/
2. Click on the bug icon
3. Click on net panel
4. See whether your request is greyed out

Comment: The only request is a post request and it is not greyed out.

Comment: Is the problem, because of caching?

Comment: Cool :) I was also confused when I faced this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why not take out the `.empty()`

```
$( "#result" ).append( content );
```

Or try

```
$( "#result" ).html( content );
```